# Plot linear difference equations

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

How can I plot an unstable node, saddle, and center in linear two-dimensional difference equations? I can plot the stable node, please see the code. Thank you in advance.

```
Clear[A, pts1, pts2, pts]

A = {{.80, 0}, {0, .64}};

pts1 = Table[NestList[A.# &, {k, 3}, 20], {k, -3, 3}];

pts2 = Table[NestList[A.# &, {k, -3}, 20], {k, -3, 3}];

p1 = ListLinePlot[pts1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}}, 

AspectRatio -> Automatic] /. 

Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]};

p2 = ListLinePlot[pts2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 

PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}}, 


AspectRatio -> Automatic] /. 

Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]};

Show[p1, p2]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: For completeness can you also add images of your plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to draw this with complex numbers: Exp[I x] will deliver the rotation and f[x] or Exp[f[x]] the distance from the origin.

```
pts = Table[
    x Exp[I (k + x)], {k, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 
     10, .1}] /. {Complex[a_, b_] -> List[a, b], a_Real -> {a, 0}};
ListLinePlot[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

Along the same lines we may draw a center:

```
pts = Table[
    x Exp[I k ], {k, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/5}, {x, 0, 
     10, .1}] /. {Complex[a_, b_] -> List[a, b], a_Real -> {a, 0}};
ListLinePlot[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

Comment: `ReIm` can be used in lieu of `/. {Complex[a_, b_] -> List[a, b], a_Real -> {a, 0}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverse the direction of the arrowhead:

```
Clear[A, pts1, pts2, pts]

A = {{.80, 0}, {0, .64}};

pts1 = Table[NestList[A.# &, {k, 3}, 20], {k, -3, 3}];

pts2 = Table[NestList[A.# &, {k, -3}, 20], {k, -3, 3}];

p1 = ListLinePlot[pts1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
    PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic] /. 
   Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, -0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]};

p2 = ListLinePlot[pts2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
    PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic] /. 
   Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, -0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]};

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel Huber. How can I find the center and spiral?

Comment: Which center and spiral?

Comment: i mean how can i change this example to get center and spiral. I try to change 
A = {{.80, 0}, {0, .64}}; to be 
A = {{1, 3}, {-1, -1}}; to get spiral .. but looks not spiral

Comment: You can update the answers that you give. I think it would be a lot better for future users if you combined your answers into one instead of the two you have now. Regardless, good answers!

Comment: Thank u so much Daniel Huber